# Two Servers One JBOD

Tags: server, cluster, mass-storage

I'm looking to create a clustered storage file server using Ubuntu 18.04.  I have two physical servers and one JBOD with 36 disks.  The goal is to setup failover file server with ZFS RAIDz2 pools on the JBOD connected by HBAs.

```
[Server A]     [Server B]
     |HBA1          |HBA2
      \->  [JBOD] <-/
```

Server A is the primary and Server B is the failover.  I've looked over several sites and documents that cover replicating data over the network to share storage in a cluster but haven't found anything physically connecting storage between two servers.  The JBOD has multiple in/out SaS connector ports (2 each).

Can anyone help me to find documentation on how to accomplish this?  I've done several days of searching and so far all of my results dead-end with replicating data between servers.  Stackoverflow had a similar discussion on a vmware [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301596/shared-mount-point-between-virtual-machines-in-vmware) for a multi-writer shared disk back in 2012 but suggested it wasn't available.  I'm hoping there might be some progress on a method or direction I can find to accomplish the goal.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki) is a good overview and walkthrough with a ZFS HA solution. Based on RHEL, but should be transferable to Ubuntu...

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to try this with CentOS to make sure it works there and work backwards to try and convert back to ubuntu OS.

Comment: That was spot on step by step for Centos and I think we can work with that and migrate it over to Ubuntu.  How do I mark your answer and close the question?

Comment: @Bensode I'm looking to do the same thing. Can you share any details about your Ubuntu port?